# ipython code completion does not support namespace package

Tags: namespaces, package, pip, ipython, setuptools

I've submitted a few packages to PyPI, `djangox-mako` and `djangox-route`. They have same namespace package `django`. When I've installed both packages, they work well. However, in IPython I cannot use completion. For example,

```
>>> import djangox.[tab]
```

in this case, I expect `djangox.route` and `djangox.mako` show up, but got no result.

So I've digged into ipython source code, and found function `module_list` in `IPython.core.completerlib.py`:

```
    for root, dirs, nondirs in os.walk(path):
        subdir = root[len(path)+1:]
        if subdir:
            files.extend(pjoin(subdir, f) for f in nondirs)
            dirs[:] = [] # Do not recurse into additional subdirectories.
        else:
            files.extend(nondirs)
```

Because `djangox` package is namespace package, it doesn't have **init**.py, so the for loop doesn't add anything to files for `djangox`.

I think it's a bug of ipython, but in pydev does the same. It means most of tool developers don't care about namespace packages. So I think it should also be fixed in setuptools namespace package support.

However, it'll take time, and it would be better if there is a workaround for that. If that's only matter of my computer, I have something.

```
touch site-packages/djangox/__init__.py
```

then both ipython and pydev work. easy_install also get this work, but it support only last-installed package using same namespace package.

```
python setup.py install
```

But I want code completion works for my package users. Is there any workaround that can get the code below work?

```
pip install djangox-mako djangox-route
ipython

>>> import djangox.[tab]
djangox.route    djangox.mako
```

Comment: Is this using the Python 3.3 namespace packages? It's not that we don't care, we just haven't got around to testing that yet, since namespace packages aren't used that much anyway.

Comment: No, I'm using Python 2.7. Are you a developer of ipython? I think if `module_list` loads *.pth files, it should work.

Comment: I've searched further and got to know that `.pth` files should be loaded only when they are in `site-packages` directory. So not the `module_list` but the `get_root_modules` should treat namespace packages. `sys.path` is not enough, but I didn't find how to load `.pth` files in `site-packages`. When I find a way, I'll send Pull Request on github.

Comment: @ThomasK I think it's definitely a fault of setuptools. I mean it's not a bug of setuptools, but a bad specification of namespace package. All of the ways to get a list of all modules do not show namespace packages. `pydoc modules`, `help(modules)`, `pkgutil.iter_modules()` all failed. I think PEP 420 should be modified.

Comment: Oh, setuptools. Yes, it's probably doing something bizarre that we don't take account of. PEP 420 specifies the namespace packages that go with Python 3.3, but we may well not handle that correctly either.